# How to dynamicaly change the data in html table

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on School time table management, my plan is like this.

I made a table, in each cell there is a link "assign". If I click that bootstrap modal will appear, in that I will select subject and teacher name. After that I will make some db operation, after that I want teacher name and subject to display on the same cell.

After displaying subject and techer name, the cell should have small close button on top rightside. So this is my plan.

I completely able to do bootstrap modal. After that I am not able to do so.

Can anyone give some idea about how to make a cell editable. Suggest me some link to refer please.

Comment: where is your relevant code? Did you make effort to search? See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you databind your table. This means that the table is generated based on the data in your database.

This way when you update your data, you just have to rebind your table and it will represent all changes made in the database.

There are many techniques to do that, via: php, html&ajax, asp.net, jsp, ... take your pick. Each technique uses it's own language, but it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: can you please share any site link for information reference.

Comment: It all depends on the technique you choose. What technique are you using to save to your database?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I saw a video , Here is the link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBFXpOsaymc I just wana table like this.

Answer (score 0):

To make a cell editable you could have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/t3qRL/2/

It's created with the prototype framework but with jQuery it would even be easier. Just grab the textvalues of the hidden textareas and replace the table cell's content with it. If your table consists of dynamically added table rows you should also have a look at jQuery's delegation or bootraps's equivalent.

I have to post the code too. So here it is:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function () {
    $$('body')[0].on('click', '.txt_area', function (event, element) {
        event.stopPropagation();        
        var div_text = element.innerHTML;
        element.hide();
        var text_area = element.next('textarea');
        text_area.show();
        text_area.value = div_text;
        text_area.onmouseover = function () {
            text_area.observe('click', function(event) {
                Event.stop(event);
            });
        }

        text_area.onmouseout = function () {                
            $$('html')[0].on('click', function () {
                console.log(text_area.value);
                element.show();
                element.update(text_area.value);
                text_area.hide();
            });
        }
    });
});
```